# Are AWS Cognito User Pool ID and App Client ID secret?

Tags: security, amazon-cognito

So 2 questions.

1. are the UserPoolId and AppClientId secret for Aws Cognito user pools?
2. if so how do you keep them secure?  All the libraries I have seen (aws-amplify/amazon-cognito-identity-js) seem to be exclusively client based.

What am I missing here.  It seems like you give any malicious user with JS access keys to the Cognito kingdom with these 2 pieces of information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are not secret.

In fact, the ID token contains the `iss` claim (property), which is the User Pool ID, and the `aud` claim, which is the App Client ID.

The Access token contains the `iss` claim, which again is the User Pool ID, while it's the `client_id` claim which represents the App Client ID.

Should either of these tokens be intercepted by a bad actor, then they can decode the tokens, as they are just base64 encoded (not encrypted).

However, just knowing these 2 pieces of information is not usually terribly useful for an attacker, as long as the JWTs are validated correctly.

It does not give the attacker access to the User Pool itself as that requires AWS credentials, which are only assigned to users, or identities that have already been properly authenticated (and then issued credentials e.g. by ID Pools).

In terms of accessing an api, an attacker might want to modify the payload in some way in order to change the data in the request. For instance they may want to change a hypothetical `role` claim from `user` to `admin` in order to escalate privileges and access areas that they shouldn't. This is mitigated by correctly validating the JWT tokens server-side to ensure that the payload has not been tampered with.

Another type of api attack could be to use a token that was correctly authenticated for one api to access another api (JWT substitution). This is mitigated by validating the `iss` and `aud` claims in order to confirm that the JWT was specifically issued to the expected User Pool and App Client.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things much easier for me and I feel better about the existing design.  Very well explained answer!

Comment: But what if an attacker uses the userpool ID and appClientId to setup a client that annoyingly creates thousands of users in a given user pool? That could fill up the user pool with fake users...

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica Given the number of bots and fake accounts, I guess that is an issue that even Twitter and Facebook have problems with. It would be interesting to know how they monitor it. I wonder if they use AI to classify the behaviour in accounts at all?

Comment: Yes, monitoring! I found out that Cognito sends "SignUp" events to cloudwatch and cloudwatch has a feature called 'anomaly detection' that uses AI to distinguish what is normal usage from what is not, triggering an alarm. There is also 'Cloudtrail', that logs the IP addresses of client API calls to Cognito.

Comment: I dont think there's any harm in exposing these. Even AWS Amplify has aws-exports.js file stored n client side which has all these values including your dyanmodb table name, api paths, s3 bucket name, etc

Comment: What happens if your application is fully serverless? you use Cognito to authenticate and then you access your APIs with the authenticated user session, with no JWT token in the middle, what should be the correct approach?