# amplify and angular security concern - cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to figure out if amplify is needed for cognito to work with the frontend or if there is a more secure way of setting it up. The reason I'm asking is because I have a solution that allows me to login to my app using cognito, amplify, and angular, but in order for it to work I have to put things like userPoolId and userPoolWebClientId in my auth.service.ts file. From a security standpoint, I feel this is a very bad thing to have in the frontend. Usually I would think that this kind of sensitive info would be stored in backend, but I haven't seen a solution that doesn't do this.

My angular app has it setup like this in auth.service.ts

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    userPoolId: '<my user pool id was here. Seems insecure>',
    userPoolWebClientId: '<my user pool id was here. Seems insecure>',
    mandatorySignIn: false,

    oauth: {
      domain: 'mysite.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
      scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      responseType: 'code'
    }
  }
});


const POOL_DATA = {
  UserPoolId: '<my user pool id was here. Seems insecure>',
  ClientId: '<my client id was here. Seems insecure>'
};

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(POOL_DATA);
...
```

Is there something I'm missing. Is there a more secure way of doing this on the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option to use AWS Cognito in front-end without pool id & web client id.

Instead of keeping the credentials in the service file I would suggest you to keep those in the environment.ts files.

1. Add credentials to environment.ts

   ```
   export const environment = {
      production: false,
      envName: 'dev',
      cognitoUserPoolId: <secure credential>,
      cognitoClientId: <secure credential>
   }
   ```
2. Create a config.ts file as a layer of abstraction.

   ```
    import { environment } from '<your folder path>/environments/environment';

    export const CONFIG = {
       UserPoolId: environment.cognitoUserPoolId,
       ClientId: environment.cognitoClientId,
    }
   ```
3. Import config file in your  auth.service.ts

   ```
    import { CONFIG } from '<your folder path>/config';

    Amplify.configure({
       Auth: {
         region: 'us-east-1',
         userPoolId: CONFIG.UserPoolId,
         userPoolWebClientId: CONFIG.ClientId,
         mandatorySignIn: false
      }
    });
   ```

This way the credentials wont be exposed to the outside world. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: well, actually you can see all these keys in the request sent to aws.. so, although they are not visible in your code, you can see them in the network tab... that being sad, env vars are just for organisation rather than "to keep them safe"

Answer (score 1):

Your right to question everything you put in the frontend, but these IDs are not sensitive. If I want to be authenticated to your application I still need to prove my identity claim to one of your chosen identity providers.

Think about other web-app implementations. You could have backend REST endpoint that accepts a post request containing the authentication credentials. The fact that I can see the javascript code and extract the url for the login endpoint doesn't make it insecure.

Protect your sensitive data in the backend with authorisation controls. You should then be (relatively) safe to assume that while everyone can load the frontend code resources, any requests they make to backend resources will be denied unless the have an appropriate valid token.

This [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703095/are-aws-cognito-user-pool-id-and-app-client-id-secret?rq=1) goes into more detail.