# What's the proper way to set up an user pool on Angular with a serverless build

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, clean-architecture

I'm working on a POC application that is completely serverless. This application is written in Angular, the authentication system is built using AWS Cognito.
The user pool was already created so I had to take the approach of reusing an existing backend as provided by Amplify docs:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js/#re-use-existing-authentication-resource

For this case, I'm not using the Hosted UI, but instead, I built my own and only consumed Amplify's methods for the whole flow.

The connection values to the user pool are in the main.ts file like this:

```
const userPoolConfig: CognitoConfig = {
  region: 'us-east-1',
  userPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxxx',
  userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
};

Amplify.configure(userPoolConfig);
Auth.configure(userPoolConfig);
```

However, I do have a concern about how to protect my user pool from being used by third-party entities if they get the `userPoolId` and `userPoolWebClientId`

What should be the right approach in this case if there's no backend on an application of the sort?

I could not find anything that answers that question on the AWS docs or Amplify.

What should be the best practice here?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I think usually it is not a concern if a third party can access your user pool, because I think of it as someone having access to my login page. They cannot login though, but the login page is usually public-facing. On the other hand, even if it is meant for a private network, then your `userPoolId` and `AppId` won't be exposed to the internet, so only those who are in the private network can access it.

Comment: Perhaps these answers would helpful in satisfying your queries/doubt about security .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772280/amplify-and-angular-security-concern-cognito and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703095/are-aws-cognito-user-pool-id-and-app-client-id-secret