# amazon-cognito-identity-js on React frontend

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

Is it safe to use `amazon-cognito-identity-js` on a frontend application given that it will have your user pool and client ID?

I am trying to use Cognito in my React app (with a Python backend). I was hoping to keep the Cognito services on the frontend and have my backend authenticate on the users token. Is this possible with `amazon-cognito-identity-js` or should I instead use Amplify? (Or is there an SDK I can use for my Python backend for Cognito?)

Comment: why not? after all you are not storing any secret.

Comment: So user pool and client ID are not considered secrets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62711877/10286256) which seems to explain how user pool and client ID are not secrets and can be stored on a frontend service. So the answer is yes, it is safe.